# FragmentTabHost return null when I get the tag of the tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

Here is how I create the tabhost, what I would like to do is get the tab when the user click on the tab. The problem is , it return null instead of the tag value.

```
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meun_home)),
            HomeFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec("form").setIndicator("",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meun_register)),
            FormFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec("calculator").setIndicator("",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meun_calculator)),
            CalculatorFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec("news").setIndicator("",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meun_call)),
            HomeFragment.class, null);

    tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(params);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                       
                    Log.d("test1",""+v.getTag());
                    return true; // doesnt allow tab change
                }
                return false;
            }               
        });
    }
```

You can find the line `Log.d("test1",""+v.getTag());` which return null. Which expected is return some string like "home" , "form", etc..... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you do not set any tag to your **View** of  your **newTabSpec**. you set drawable icon but you do not set any **Tag**. So you can do it in two ways:

1) first create an **imageView** from your drawable icon:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

and then set **Tag** to your **imageView** and use `setIndicator(View view)` to add it to your **newTabSpec**.

2) or after you add your drawable you can use **getChildTabViewAt()** to get the View and then set the **Tag** for it.

in summary you have not set any tag so it is obviously null.

the doc says:

> TabHost.TabSpec:
>
> A tab has a tab indicator, content, and a tag that is used to keep
>   track of it. This builder helps choose among these options. For the
>   tab indicator, your choices are: 1) set a label 2) set a label and an
>   icon For the tab content,

so that string is just a label, the `tag` and the label is two different things, `tag` is  memory of a `view` that you can store any `object` in to it that object can be a `string` or anything else like ViewHolder design pattern that used in creating listview.

Comment: Thanks , and what is .newTabSpec added, is it a tag or some id that I can reference to ?

Comment: Thanks for the update! so I can not get the newTabSpec but I need to set the tag at that icon?

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution 2) as recommended by the last answered author:

```
View vv = tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
vv.setTag("mytag_"+i);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment to the other answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Cheers.